# Asp.Net C# - DataAccess GetRow Doesn't Exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm a new-born programmer so I am NOT experienced, nor do I understand all the fancy terms you guys know and use ;)

But, as something new I've been looking into DataAccess (BLL I think it's called), I wan't to retrieve informations from my SQL Database but I get this error: 
*"GetRow Does Not Exist In the Current Context"*

Here are my pages:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Forside") %>' />
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess("DrinkOnlineConnectionString");
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@id", "1");
        DataRow row = GetRow("SELECT Forside FROM [Tekster] WHERE id = @id");
        if (row != null)
        {
            lblDescription.Text = row["Forside"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Please remember, I am still new to programming. :)

Comment: Do you have the correct using statement and references added?

Comment: Are you sure it shouldn't be dataAccess.GetRow("SELECT ...") - where is the method GetRow defined?

Comment: Hey mate, oh yeam I suppose. A friend of mine made the DataAccess file and said to use the code above to retrieve info from the database. But the ONLY error I get is that "GetRow" doesn't exist. I hope I answered your question :)

Comment: Get Row is in the DataAccess like this:     public DataRow GetRow(string query)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = GetDataTable(query);

        if (dataTable != null && dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            return dataTable.Rows[0];
        return null;
    }

Comment: Try this DataRow row = dataAccess.GetRow("SELECT Forside FROM [Tekster] WHERE id = @id");

Comment: @MikeBertelsen See answer below. Basically, you need to call the method on dataAccess. Does your code even build?

Comment: Cheers everyone, thank you for looking into this! I really apprecaite it. The issue was, as some people already mentioned. Mine was "GetRow("SELECT")", it should be changed to "dataAccess.GetRow("SELECT")"

Comment: @MikeBertelsen Good luck, and don't be afraid to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
DataRow row = dataAccess.GetRow("SELECT Forside FROM [Tekster] WHERE id = @id");
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't have that dataAccess.GetRow, mine was just GetRow. Thank you Sir.

Answer (score 1):

based on your comment, try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)     
    {         
        DataAccess dataAccess = new DataAccess("DrinkOnlineConnectionString");         
        dataAccess.AddParameter("@id", "1");         
        DataRow row = dataAccess.GetRow("SELECT Forside FROM [Tekster] WHERE id = @id");         

        if (row != null)         
        {             
            lblDescription.Text = row["Forside"].ToString();         
        }     
    }
```

You need to call the GetRow method on the dataAccess object.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to repeat the set text operation.

If you left the asp page with no text:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="" />
```

And set the text in the C# code, it will works.

Comment: Cheers mate, what do you mean with "repeat the set text operation"?:)

Comment: When you set in aspx file (using Text='<%# Eval("Forside") %>' />) and cs file (using lblDescription.Text = row["Forside"].ToString();) you are repeating the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

Just change code in .aspx as below:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<asp:Label ID="lblDescription" runat="server" Text="" />
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

Same as you've, good code!